# CSV Python column/line averages

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, mean

I am trying to get this solution (right below) without using Panda, Basically what I want to do is get the Averages of healthy patients and Ill patients
in a CSV file. The file has 303 patients with 14 categories (so 13 rows) Some of the data is missing so its replaced with ?'s Row 13 separates Ill patients from healthy by anything greater than 0 is ill and anything = or below 0 is healthy. I have found a way to split them but I do know know how to add up the lines to get the averages for the healthy patients and Ill patients separately. Any ideas on how to proceed would be awesome

```
 Please enter a training file name: train.csv
    Total Lines Processed: 303
    Total Healthy Count: 164
    Total Ill Count: 139
    Averages of Healthy Patients:
    [52.59, 0.56, 2.79, 129.25, 242.64, 0.14, 0.84, 158.38, 0.14, 0.59, 1.41, 0.27, 3.77, 0.00]
    Averages of Ill Patients:
    [56.63, 0.82, 3.59, 134.57, 251.47, 0.16, 1.17, 139.26, 0.55, 1.57, 1.83, 1.13, 5.80, 2.04]
    Seperation Values are:
    [54.61, 0.69, 3.19, 131.91, 247.06, 0.15, 1.00, 148.82, 0.34, 1.08, 1.62, 0.70, 4.79, 1.02]
```

I still have a long way to go on my code, I'm just looking for a simplistic way to get the averages of the patients. My current method only gets column 13 but I need all 13 like above. Any help on which way I should try to go with solving this would be awesome and much appreciated.

```
import csv
#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     csv_data = list(reader)

i_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
        i_list.append(int(row[13]))
H_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if (row and int(row[13]) <= 0):
        H_list.append(int(row[13]))
for row in reader:

Icount = len(i_list)
IPavg = sum(i_list)/len(i_list)
Hcount = len(H_list)
HPavg = sum(H_list)/len(H_list)
file = open("train.csv")
numline = len(file.readlines())

print(numline)
print("Total amount of healthy patients " + str(Icount))
print("Total amount of ill patients " + str(Hcount))
print("Averages of healthy patients " + str(HPavg))
print("Averages of ill patients " + str(IPavg)
```

Example of what was asked in comments

```
CVS File
A         B        C       D   N(so on to column 13) 
10        .50      ?       44   0
4         4.5      20      34   0
12         ?       33      23   3 (this one would be Ill patient)
11         3.2     32       33   0
[![CSVfile][1]][1]
```

Screen shot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should try numpy's average: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.average.html Makes it much much easier to do statistical work :)

Comment: Could you expand on this: "My current method only gets column 13 but I need all 13 like above."

Comment: @Adib yes I know of numpy's to an extent though I am unable to use it for this problem due to the fact that we haven't gone through it yet in my class the same with pandas. 
As for the 13 column part What my current code does is only get the information of column 13 which is kind of needed since that is what tells me whether the patient is health or not. But after I know if they are healthy I need to ad each column's number of those healthy patients so I can get the Averages for them.

Comment: I can't correctly put the example so I'll put it in the main question

Comment: Can you share a few lines from train.csv data

Comment: @Adib I put both an example and screenshot since the ?'s are in random spots I wanted to make sure you know that they are in there still just randomly.

Comment: Is there a way to make an if statement stating if row 13 is <=0 add lines? 
and the same for if its greater that way I can get the sum and average

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108976/discussion-between-david-and-adib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full thing with tutorial (the comments). Please read through them if you wish to understand how to master python.

```
import csv

#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv','rU') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     csv_data = list(reader)

# Create two lists to handle the patients
# And two more lists to collect the 'sum' of the columns
# The one that needs to hold the sum 'must' have 0 so we 
# can work with them more easily
iList = []
iList_sum = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

hList = []
hList_sum = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

# Only use one loop to make the process mega faster
for row in csv_data:
    # If row 13 is greater than 0, then place them as unhealthy
    if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
        # This appends the whole 'line'/'row' for storing :)
        # That's what you want (instead of saving only one cell at a time)
        iList.append(row)

    # If it failed the initial condition (greater than 0), then row 13
    # is either less than or equal to 0. That's simply the logical outcome
    else:
        hList.append(row)

# Use these to verify the data and make sure we collected the right thing
# print iList
# [['67', '1', '4', '160', '286', '0', '2', '108', '1', '1.5', '2', '3', '3', '2'], ['67', '1', '4', '120', '229', '0', '2', '129', '1', '2.6', '2', '2', '7', '1']]
# print hList
# [['63', '1', '1', '145', '233', '1', '2', '150', '0', '2.3', '3', '0', '6', '0'], ['37', '1', '3', '130', '250', '0', '0', '187', '0', '3.5', '3', '0', '3', '0']]

# We can use list comprehension, but since this is a beginner task, let's go with basics:

# Loop through all the 'rows' of the ill patient 
for ill_data in iList:

    # Loop through the data within each row, and sum them up
    for i in range(0,len(ill_data) - 1):
        iList_sum[i] += float(ill_data[i])


# Now repeat the process for healthy patient
# Loop through all the 'rows' of the healthy patient 
for healthy_data in hList:

    # Loop through the data within each row, and sum them up
    for i in range(0,len(healthy_data) - 1):
        hList_sum[i] += float(ill_data[i])

# Using list comprehension, I basically go through each number
# In ill list (sum of all columns), and divide it by the lenght of iList that
# I found from the csv file. So, if there are 22 ill patients, then len(iList) will
# be 22. You can see that the whole thing is wrapped in brackets, so it would show
# as a python list

ill_avg = [ ill / len(iList) for ill in iList_sum]
hlt_avg = [ hlt / len(hList) for hlt in hList_sum]

# Do whatever....
```

Comment: Thanks man can I message you if I have questions about something in the code?

I looking for more of how to mast this better I have actual assignment I have to do but needed to figure out how to do this one before I could get started on the next one so I'm really trying to understand it all. Thanks again I really appreciate the notes on there.

Comment: @David Sure. Don't rely on me though :) I like to simply practice my own coding by helping others

Comment: haha thanks but no I won't rely on you i meant it would  take me a while to fully comprehend this stuff i like to be thorough so if I had any questions about it I was wondering if I could just poke your brain about it. Though it seems really well explained